# How to automatically classify words in the dictionary?

Tags: language-agnostic, data-mining, classification

I have a large dictionary file, dic.txt (its actually the [SOWPODS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOWPODS)) with one word from the English language per line. I want to automatically split this file into 3 different files easy_dic.txt (most common every day words we use - vocabulary of a 16 year old), medium_dic.txt (words not that much in common usage but still known to many people - knowledge of a 30 year old minus words found in easy_dic.txt), hard_dic.txt (very esoteric words that only professional Scrabble players would know). What's the easiest way (you can use any resources from the internet) to accomplish this?

Comment: Rather open-ended. With only the dictionary file this is not possible.

Comment: Well, obviously you are allowed to use any resource available from the internet. I was wondering if there was any API that was available. I don't think the question is open-ended, it's very clear what needs to be done.

Comment: @Oded May be you are right, but the problem is very interesting, and has many useful outcomes. I came across this same issue when trying to make a module to generate suggestions for misspelled words. By suggesting the most common words (within a certain edit distance interval) the guessing ability of the software increased a lot.

Comment: @belisarius - yes my use case is a Scrabble like game with 3 difficulty levels where the AI uses more esoteric words in higher difficulty levels.

Comment: Put in a 16 year old, a 30 year old and a professional Scrabble player into your algorithm!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google has the right tool :), and shares its DB!

The [**Ngram viewer**](https://googleblog.blogspot.com/2010/12/find-out-whats-in-word-or-five-with.html) is a tool to check out and compare the frequency of appearance of words in literature, magazines, etc.

You can download the DB, and train your dictionaries from [here](http://storage.googleapis.com/books/ngrams/books/datasetsv2.html).

HTH!

BTW The tool is VERY fun to use and discover the word's birth and disappearance dates.

Comment: To add to this answer, you probably want to look at the list of unigrams on that page. For cut-offs, you could take what you consider borderline easy, borderline medium and borderline obscure, find counts of those words, and then make lists by thresholding on those counts

Answer (score 0):

- Take some books (preferably from you three categories) that are available in a computer-readable form.
- Create histograms for all words from those books.
- Merge the histograms for all books from each category.
- When processing your dictionary, check in which category's histogram the word has the highest count and put the word in this category.

Instead of the last step you could also simply process your histograms and remove a word from all histograms except the one with the highest amount of hits. Then you already have a word list without using an external dictionary file.

Answer (score 0):

Download Wikipedia dump, learn word frequencies with some Lingpipe tool(optimal data structures). Check words from dictionaries frequency distribution then split them to 3 groups.